Unable to trigger Power Automate flow using python script
I am trying to send message on teams using a python script using Power Automate.
import requests  # Import requests library
import datetime

# Get current time.
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Triggering Power Automate Flow
flow_url='https://***/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01'  # Replace with actual URL from step 2

response=requests.post(flow_url,json={"status":"Script Completed","timestamp":now})

if response.status_code==200:
     print('PowerAutomate Flow triggered successfully')
else:
     print(f'Failed to trigger PowerAutomate Flow: {response.status_code}')

Error:
Failed to trigger PowerAutomate Flow: 401

Power Automate Flow:

Full Flow:


Can you check your URL again in your flow?  If you've changed that to Anyone after you copied the URL then it will have changed to add a sig on the back of it.

Thanks that changed the error code, now it is Failed to trigger PowerAutomate Flow: 202

Ok, so first issue has been solved by updating your URL as instructed.
Next, the 202 isn't an error, it means that the request has been accepted and the flow will run asynchronously.
If you want to wait and return values or a successful (200) response to your calling application then you need to put a Response operation in the flow at the point where the response needs to be made.  It's awesome architecture, you can put it anywhere you want and the flow will keep running.

Not adding that in your flow will generate an immediate 202 and respond directly to your calling application.

Thanks, This worked easily, I do have one more query regarding licensing, I am not sure I am doing all this under free Tier of Power Automate? The 5 tasks of this flow I have attached in OP above.

Uhhhh, I think you're ok.  If it turns out you're not, flick over to Azure LogicApps, it's the same engine with some slight differences, none of which should affect you.
